# replace integer with string in query

Tags: mysql

I have searched for an answer and have not been able to find one.

I have a table that records an integer instead of text.  I am trying to run a query and substitute text for a specific integer.

here are the integers in column cal_referral_type (this column is int) with the correlating text it represents:

```
DO NOT TRACK|1
Carey Guide |2
Education   |3
Employment  |4
Housing     |5
Medical     |6
```

I need to run a report to see how many referrals are going to each category but staff get confused with just the number.

If I run a query:

```
SELECT cal_owner,cal_title,cal_referral_type 
FROM egw_cal 
WHERE cal_referral_type = 3
```

It shows all referrals to educational services but the column results in a "3" instead of descriptive text "education"

I have read that I can use a CASE Statement such as:

```
SELECT cal_owner,cal_title, CASE cal_referral_type
WHEN 1 THEN 'NA' ELSE 'other' FROM `egw_cal`
```

Each time I twist the query a different way, it just errors.

So, is there a way I can have the results of the query show "education" each time the integer "3" is identified?  I will expand to include all categories once I can get one to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CASE statement should work, but a better/more flexible approach is to have a lookup table with the integer values and descriptive text, and then join to that table and pull the text out. This makes changes easier to implement, as you update/add to the lookup table instead of altering code. It also helps implement user-friendly interfaces in a cleaner way if you need to do that.

Comment: Harper,  Thanks for the response.  Would you have any idea why my query will not work?  I am not sure if I can create another table without the developer's permission.  That is why I was hoping to substitute a descriptive word for the integer that is in the table when I run a query

Comment: The biggest thing I can see in your posted code is the missing "END CASE" (e.g. SELECT cal_owner, cal_title, CASE cal_referral_type WHEN 1 THEN 'NA' ELSE 'other' END CASE AS referral_type FROM 'egw_cal'. The reference page is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: Thanks again!  When I use your query above this is the error I receive:

Comment: When I use your query above this is the error I receive:  Error

SQL query:
SELECT cal_owner, cal_title,
CASE cal_referral_type
WHEN 1
THEN 'NA'
ELSE 'other'
END CASE AS referral_type
FROM 'egw_cal'
LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE AS referral_type FROM 'egw_cal'
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: I found the solution.  The complete query adds in date.  Here is how it looks:  SELECT cal_owner, cal_title,
FROM_UNIXTIME(range_start, "%Y-%m-%d")AS Date,
CASE cal_referral_type 
WHEN 1 THEN 'NoReferral' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'CareyGuide'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Education'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Employment'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Housing'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Medical'
ELSE 'NA' END  AS referrals FROM `egw_cal`                                 There were some grave typo's that were the main problems  Thanks for  your input as it get me going in the right direction

Comment: Happy to help. If I had a nickel for every time typos caused errors, I would be sipping fruity drinks on a tropical beach right now!