# MySQL SELECT with case to replace integer field with text

Tags: mysql, mariadb, case

Hi i need to replace an integer field with the respective text, it is not a variable thing, using a join would be a waste for this.

The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `mesas_cab` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and my query is

```
SELECT
mesas_cab.id,
mesas_cab.cid,
mesas_cab.vid,
mesas_cab.status,
usuarios.NOME,
clientes.RAZAOSOCIAL,
CASE mesas_cab.status
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Livre'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Ocupada'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Fechada'
END CASE as status_str
FROM
mesas_cab
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON mesas_cab.vid = usuarios.CODIGO
LEFT JOIN clientes ON mesas_cab.cid = clientes.CODIGO
```

i have seen this answer
[replace integer with string in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682450/replace-integer-with-string-in-query)

but my query is still giving me syntax errors

```
[SQL] SELECT
mesas_cab.id,
mesas_cab.cid,
mesas_cab.vid,
mesas_cab.status,
usuarios.NOME,
clientes.RAZAOSOCIAL,
CASE mesas_cab.status
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Livre'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Ocupada'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Fechada'
END CASE as status_str
FROM
mesas_cab
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON mesas_cab.vid = usuarios.CODIGO
LEFT JOIN clientes ON mesas_cab.cid = clientes.CODIGO

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE as status_str
FROM
mesas_cab
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON mesas_cab.vid = usuar' at line 12
```

but when i remove the whole case statement the query works almost as planned(the joins are okay)

Comment: you don't need `CASE` after the `END` i.e. `CASE mesas_cab.status ... END AS status_str`

Comment: @Nick is right.  Also you may want an ELSE clause in your CASE to cover unexpected `status` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case statement doesn't seem to be done correctly. The correct format is usually
CASE
  WHEN x = 1 then 'y'
  WHEN x = 2 then 'z'
  ELSE NULL
END AS `column_name`

So in our case it should be something like

```
SELECT
mesas_cab.id,
mesas_cab.cid,
mesas_cab.vid,
mesas_cab.status,
usuarios.NOME,
clientes.RAZAOSOCIAL,
CASE 
    WHEN mesas_cab.status = 0 THEN 'Livre'
    WHEN mesas_cab.status = 1 THEN 'Ocupada'
    WHEN mesas_cab.status = 2 THEN 'Fechada'
    ELSE NULL
END as status_str
FROM
mesas_cab
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON mesas_cab.vid = usuarios.CODIGO
LEFT JOIN clientes ON mesas_cab.cid = clientes.CODIGO
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was following the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html too and it was confusing.